# Fire button action then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2

I have a textarea element that `onfocus` three buttons appear, then `onblur` those buttons suppose to hide (display=none), my problem is when I click on any of the three buttons, they hide before firing the action, I need the button to do the action the fire the `onblur` and hide.

```
 <h:inputTextarea styleClass="mmagd_2sms_create_template_erea toeditsavedtemp"
        value="#{bean.text}" onfocus="tempTextFocus(this)" id="temp-text" />
        <ul class="actionsList flipped buttontosavetemp">

            <li class=""><h:commandLink styleClass="overlayClose"
                             value="#{msgs.delete}" onclick="hideEditTemp(this)"
                             action="#{templateBean.deleteTemplate}">
                                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{templateBean.templateDelObj}" value="#{bean}" />
                                 <f:ajax execute=":template-form"
                                 render=":template-form:user-temp-list" event="action" />
                        </h:commandLink></li>
            <li class=""><h:commandLink styleClass="overlayClose black" value="#{msgs.cancel}"
                             onclick="hideEditTemp(this)">
                             <f:ajax />
                        </h:commandLink></li>

            <li class=""><h:commandLink value="#{msgs.save}"
                             styleClass="overlayClose active"
                             action="#{templateBean.editTemplate}" onclick="hideEditTemp(this)">
                             <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{templateBean.templateObj}" value="#{bean}" />
                             <f:ajax execute=":template-form" render=":template-form:user-temp-list" />
                        </h:commandLink></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I think in this case you shouldn't use the onblur event as any click outside your textarea causes it to loose focus. Better think about a workaround. It could be for example that you trigger the "hide" when user clicks anywhere else on the page but the buttons for example.  That said, you shouldn't use inline javascript (= `onclick` attribute)

Comment: This is also a good idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must use a outline script, use jQuery or js event handler in script tag, page, then use a callback function, its will execute after fire event was execute, I supose using another event handler ..

[Read here about callback function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp)

any way this example may help you

```
$("textarea").focus(function () {
   // Execute fire action on foucse
}).blur(function () {
   // After finshed do Some code here
});
```

in example Im not using a callback since your trigger is focuse, if you changes your event you can using a callback

Comment: This is a partial solution, another problem is how to get the object of the user clicked to do action on. But this is a start so thanks :D

Comment: You are Welcome, 

about user object(are you mean user event object, or object was saved in script to do somthing?), 

if is a user event object, you can add a char between function parentheses like this .focus(function (e)...

if is hte option tow, you can save an object in variable ..and then using a variable as a object like this
var userOb = $(this);// when you can get an user object(global variable)

then in any where you can use a userOb like userOb.show()// example